# How to configure priorities for Spark and OpenMPI to coexist on a cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, cluster-computing, openmpi

We have a small cluster running Spark to execute jobs from a public-facing web application.  The goal of using Spark here is to have an efficient latency for the web app, so when a job is submitted, it needs a response from the cluster as soon as possible.

However much of the time it is idle.  So when it's needed, Spark needs to be fast, but when it's not needed, we'd like to use these computing resources otherwise.

For example we have some simulations to run that use OpenMP for local threading and OpenMPI to distribute processing across the cluster.  These take some time to run, and we'd like to use the cluster only when it is not needed by Spark.

Is it possible to configure Spark to have very high priority and knock-out or starve other programs?  From Spark's [configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) I see several options regarding limiting memory and cores used, but not much related to giving Spark higher priority.

We are thinking about using [Torque](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque) to control the job queue for the OpenMPI simulations.  We're thinking about running them inside Docker containers so as to make it easy to update them, as they are in development.  The idea is to issue a Torque command that will basically pull a Docker image, start it up on each machine, and trigger the OpenMPI application.  Is this too convoluted?  Any other recommendations?  Can we drop Torque and directly use Spark to also control the OpenMPI jobs?  Can one Spark job interrupt another if it has higher priority?

Everything is running on Fedora at the moment.

**tl;dr**

The larger question here is, how can we launch long-running compute-intensive distributed jobs on a cluster while still ensuring good latency from a Spark instance that coexists on the same hardware?

** This post may betray my relative unfamiliarity with Spark..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by default, spark slave tries to use all the resources of the node it is in - so your question is mainly about how to reduce the priority of other processes in your nodes.

An automatic solution is to use the nice Linux command - but it might be too simplified depends on your cluster configuration (give spark higher priority than other resources on you machine).

Another approach is to implement your custom behavior, and it all depends on how you deploy spark, which cluster manager you use and the nature of the other services in your cluster.

For example - one simple way to accomplish this if you use docker swarm as your cluster manager together with spark stand alone:
have the spark slaves up and running (they don't use many resources when they are idle) together with more services on the same nodes.
When a job will arrive to spark - you can scale all other services on the spark slaves nodes down. This will work fine if your other services can be brought down and up...

If you use Mesos as your cluster manager - you can use the same trick, and you can also implement your own mesos scheduler or allocator

BTW - one other trivial solution is to just allocate unique resources to spark. I guess you already thought about it, but I urge you to give it another thought :-). This way you'll be able to predict the SLA to all the other services in the cluster as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "When a job will arrive to spark  - you can scale all other services on the spark slaves nodes down."
yeah i would even maybe pause them.. is there a way to configure this?